# Variables Naming Conventions- var1,var2 or firstVar, secondVar?

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

In cases where you have 2 variables from the same type that play a similar roll, like for example a merge function of 2 arrays:
IntArray merge(IntArray  array1,IntArray  array2);

What do you think is the best (most readable, least error-prone) way to name the variables? **var1,var2** or **firstVar,secondVar**? or maybe a different way?
If you express your opinion, I would be glad to hear the rational behind, especially regarding which is less error-prone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: C++. I though about tagging it, but the issues really seems language-independent.

Answer (score 2):

For C/C++, I think the following would be preferred:

```
IntArray merge(IntArray a, IntArray b);
```

Because it's simple, short and avoids using integers in the variable names.

Or the 'operator form':

```
IntArray merge(IntArray lhs, IntArray rhs);
```

(for *left-hand side* and *right-hand side*)

(alike:

```
IntArray operator+(IntArray lhs, IntArray rhs);
```

)

The 'numeric' variants, and camelCase are more like ECMAScript than C. But it's mostly a 'standard' created by people who simply used C/C++ and used naming like that (see [plus template in C++ standard library](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/plus/) for an example).

But you can't get much rationale behind it because it's simply a matter of taste. As long as the variables are equally important (i.e. `merge(a, b) == merge(b, a)`), it's just how they will referred from the implementation code.

Comment: the plus template in C++ might very well contain different variables names in the implementation/definition of the function (not the x and y that appear in the signature of the declaration).

I'm most interested in a solution that is the least error-prone

Comment: writing a where you need to write b or vice-versa

Comment: Err, if the variables are equally important, then I believe no naming can make it less or more error-prone. Unless you have a very specific use case, it all could fall down to counting whether there is the same number of `a`s as `b`s…

Comment: I agree it seems difficult to avoid it using a naming convention, but is what I am trying to address. I upvoted the answer but it doesn't prove the fact that the situation I'm refering is unavoidable (to be eligible for the bounty)

Comment: @JohnnyW: maybe we could think out something better if you provided some example implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, I use purpose of the variable as name instead of numeric number. It instantly tell me that the variable count is finite. For example:

```
function predicate(int subject, int object)

function merge_array(array firstArray, array secondArray)
```

Using `(array1, array2)` sounds wrong for me because it seems like there is array3, array4, ... while we know the variable/parameter count is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments of a function should always be talking about who they are and about what they should be used for. If there's non difference between the two arrays (as the source and the destination, for example), maybe you should think about passing a list of arrays (named arraysToMerge or something like that).
Variable's name has to explain variable's purpose, always. Because code is (or at least should be) our real documentation.

Comment: list of arrays has the disadvantage that it won't allow the caller the normal calling syntax and he will have to explicitly construct the list (which will also involve copying and hurt performance in C++)

Comment: I can agree talking about the merging arrays issue, because it's very specific and has a consolidated arguments' order.. I was trying to generalise the issue. 

Focusing on your question, I'd avoid names with numbers (like array1, array2..) because they let you image that there could be more than two. You should find something more specific, even if it sounds strange. 

Something like: 
function merge_array(array firstOutOfTwo, array secondOutOfTwo)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use something along the lines of `var` and `anotherVar`. 
Such as:

```
IntArray merge(IntArray array, IntArray anotherArray);
```

Variables and parameters should be self-explanatory. I think the situation is described more clearly this way.